# TypeOrm Postgres case sensitive on where clause value

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I'm using TypeOrm in a NestJs Web Api pointing to a Postgres database.  I'm having case-sensitivity issues with my select queries.

This is my NestJs controller Search method:

```js
  search(payload: SearchPayload): Promise<Password[]> {
    const user = payload.user;
    const filterBy: string = payload.searchCriteria.filterBy;
    
    let obj = {};
    obj[filterBy] = Like('%' + payload.searchCriteria.searchTerm + '%');
    obj['user'] = user.email;

    const whereClause = { where: obj };

    return this.passwordRepository.find(whereClause);
  }
```

This is the result of `whereClause` passed into the `Find` method of the service:

```js
{
  where: {
    webSiteName: FindOperator {
      _type: 'like',
      _value: '%plumbing%',
      _useParameter: true,
      _multipleParameters: false
    },
    user: 'demo@email.com'
  }
}
```

This is the `SearchPayload` object:

```js
export class SearchCriteria {
    @IsString()
    @IsOptional()
    searchTerm?: string;

    @IsOptional()
    filterBy?: string;

    @IsNumber()
    @IsOptional()
    groupId?: number;
}

export class SearchPayload {
    user: User;
    searchCriteria: SearchCriteria;
}
```

This is the object I'm passing to the api endpoint in PostMan:

```json
{
    "searchTerm": "plumbing",
    "filterBy": "webSiteName"
}
```

In PostMan, this is the record I want returned:

```json
    {
        "id": 2,
        "webSiteName": "Jim's Plumbing",
        "url": "https://www.jplumbing.com",
        "login": "demo",
        "password": "99a943d61668e0c807669a4d9deb3bb4:b17fa244ca3b9ebd42df06e94e190d5b",
        "notes": "Check inventory tomorrow",
        "user": "demo@email.com",
        "shared": false
    }
```

The problem is the case-sensitivity of the search value of the PostgreSQL.

If I search for `plumbing` I get nothing returned.  I have to search for `Plumbing` to see the results. (notice the upper-case 'P' in plumbing)

I can't required users to know the casing of the value they are searching on.  How do I get around this case-sensitivity issue?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but try to change _type: 'like' to _type: 'ilike'

Comment: @MTilsted - I didn't even know this was available.  Thanks, I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an insensitive-case where clause in Postgres you can use [ILIKE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/functions-matching.html).

For your case replace

```
 obj[filterBy] = Like('%' + payload.searchCriteria.searchTerm + '%');
```

With:

```
 obj[filterBy] = `ILIKE '%${payload.searchCriteria.searchTerm}%'`;
```

Or

```
this.passwordRepository.createQueryBuilder()
.where(`ILIKE :searchTerm`, {searchTerm: `%${payload.searchCriteria.searchTerm}`})
.andWhere(`user = :user`, {user: user.email})
.gerMany()
```

Comment: I created something like this based on MTilsted's comment.  But I like your solution also.